# Use of Timer in BlackBerry project

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, timer, timertask

I'm trying to use Timer in my BlackBerry project in this manner -

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        pushScreen(new MyScreen()); 
    }
},200);
```

but I'm getting a Runtime Exception while executing the program.
Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code? Or any other tips for using the Timer in a BlackBerry project.

My goal is to push SplashScreen for 10 sec and then MyScreen page will be open. So I want to use timer for a 10 second delay while opening the MyScreen page and during the timer I will display the SplashScreen page.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I'm working on "BlackBerry Java sdk 7.1 " in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Richard mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14035405/119114), you are having problems because you're attempting to manipulate the UI from a thread other than the main (aka "UI") thread.   You just need a small change to make your code work properly:

```java
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                                public void run() {
                                                    pushScreen(new MyScreen()); 
                                                }
                                             }, 
                                             200   /* delay */, 
                                             false /* repeat = no */);
```

The above is the equivalent of the code you posted, for BlackBerry Java.

> My goal is to push SplashScreen for 10 sec and then MyScreen page will
>   be open. So I want to use timer for a 10 second delay while opening
>   the MyScreen page and during the timer I will display the SplashScreen
>   page.

If this is actually what you want to do, then just make your `SplashScreen` appear as soon as the app is launched:

```java
public class MyApp extends UiApplication
{
   /**
    * Entry point for application
    * @param args Command line arguments (not used)
    */ 
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // Create a new instance of the application and make the currently
      // running thread the application's event dispatch thread.
      MyApp theApp = new MyApp();       
      theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
   }

   public MyApp()
   {        
      // Push a screen onto the UI stack for rendering.
      final SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen();
      pushScreen(splashScreen); 

      UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                                      public void run() {
                                                          pushScreen(new MyScreen()); 
                                                          popScreen(splashScreen);
                                                      }
                                                   }, 
                                                   10*1000   /* delay in msec */, 
                                                   false /* repeat = no */);

   }
```

This does what you asked, but the link that Richard provides also allows the user to dismiss the splash screen early.  That may or may not be what you want, so I simply offer the alternative above.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what exactly is going wrong, but one thing that you should not do is interact with the user interface on a thread that is not the event thread.

It won't teach you how to use timers but there is a [developer article](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-splash-screen/ta-p/444959) on how to do a splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing a new screen every 200 ms...
You need to kill the timer when the screen is pushed. And remember that the interval is in milliseconds, so you need to calculate that.

Good luck!